# Is there a web-based corpus tools that I can upload and use with my own corpus?

Tags: corpora, online-resources, tools

I am looking for a ready-made concordancer or collocator with a simple search interface that I can upload on my website and have my students use to search a custom corpus. I have been working with AntConc but want something that students don't need to download or run. Are there any tools like this?

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, you may want to try and ask this on the Antconc mailing list (and repost subsequent answer here).

Answer (score 4):

The [IMS Open Corpus Workbench](http://cwb.sourceforge.net/) might work for you.